# Slides.InsertFromFile does not insert correctly slides containing SVG images

Tags: vba, office365, ms-office, interop, powerpoint

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint` assembly to do presentation manipulations in VSTO-Addin application.

I figured out that the method:

`Slides.InsertFromFile(string FileName, int Index, int SlideStart, int SlideEnd)`

does not work when the inserted slide(s) contain SVG image.

There is no exception but when the presentation is opened in PowerPoint the image is displayed with a "red cross" sign like the image is missing, or the link to it is missing.

Further, I have investigated the PowerPoint file content (by renaming it to .zip). I figured out that when I use the interop method there are no copied binary files in the `\ppt\media` folder. When I insert SVG file directly from PowerPoint the same directory contains the files: `image1.png` and `image2.svg`

So, I think that Microsoft's API does not handle this case - insert of slides with SVG files.

Any ideas on how to go further with this?

**Used versions:**

- Microsoft PowerPoint 365 ProPlus: Version 1812 (Build 11126.20188)
- Microsoft Windows: Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.472)
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll 15.0.0.0 (C#)

Comment: "PowerPoint" is a moving target. Please mention version (365, 2019, 2016 etc), and build number. In Windows PPT 365 insider build, using SVG icons inserted into PPT, I can't repro this with VBA like call activepresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile("c:\temp\pptx_with_svg.pptx",1,1,1)
The problem might be due to the specific SVG, to interop or to the version of PPT you have. To eliminate two variables, try with an SVG inserted as Icon from the ribbon and then use the VBA above.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg The faulty behaviour is not in a specific version or a specific image. I pointed my current versions. Based on my previous experience Microsoft added support to SVG after Microsoft Office 2010. Could it be that the programmatic support for SVG is coming in future version of the Interop libraries?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you'd indicated versions and such. I just updated one of my ProPlus computers to the same version of Office as yours (well, mine calls itself PowerPoint 2016 rather than 365). I tested again with the same VBA as I mentioned above and had no problems. My guess (and that's all it is) would be that the interop libraries aren't updated; not too surprising, as SVG support was only added to 2016/365 quite recently.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I am suspecting absolutely the same -  the interop assemblies are not updated to use the SVG capabilities. However, I can't find any information when it will the next Interop release and most importantly if Microsoft acknowledges the problem and expects to make a fix.

Comment: I'm looking around for any further information about this and will post back if I find anything. Meanwhile, I was considering possible workarounds; one might be to insert the slide as you're doing, then open the source presentation (windowlessly), delete all images from the inserted slide, then Copy/PasteSpecial/As PNG any images on the source slide. There'd be some add'l work involved, like sending each image to the correct Z-order after pasting.

Comment: I've heard back from a contact at MS after reporting the problem to them. He'd like to get sample files (the SVG in question, a sample PPTX file and code that repros the problem).  If that's possible, please zip up the files and put them on Dropbox/OneDrive or the like and post a link to the files here. Naturally, remove any sensitive/personally identifiable information first. He's unable/not permitted to help directly here, so it might be a good idea if you include a text file with contact information (email, phonenumber etc) in the zip.